# ListPlot With Two Data Sets in Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a cleaner way to do the following, assuming that I have a reason to keep the data sets independent?:

```
x = {1, 2, 3};
y = {1, 4, 9};

ListPlot[Partition[Riffle[x, y], 2]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I do not think Timo's solution is standard.
Here are two methods, using `Transpose` or `Thread`, that I have often seen used.

```
x = {1, 2, 3};
y = {1, 4, 9};
Transpose[{x, y}]
Thread[{x, y}]
```

Output:

```
{{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}}
{{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}}
```

Both of these methods avoid explicitly referencing the length of your data which is plus in my book.

Answer (score 14):

ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}]]

Comment: And it is even cleaner if you use the Transpose short notation: {x,y} ESC tr ESC

Answer (score -1):

```
ListPlot[{x,y}]
```

EDIT: @Davorak: it certainly will. If OP wants 'y against x' then

```
ListPlot[y]
```

would suffice.  Either way, I don't understand the complicated answers to a very simple question.  But then, I don't understand a lot of the questions on SO.

Comment: I do not think so. This will plot two separate trends.