# How to combine two lists to plot coordinate pairs?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have read x-data (from text files) into list1, and y-data similarly into list2:

```
list1 = { 0.0,    0.172,  0.266, ..}
list2 = {-5.605, -5.970, -6.505, ..}
```

How do I combine the two lists in order to plot points {0.0, -5.605}, {0.172, -5.970}, {0.266, -6.505},....

Comment: maybe you want to try: `Riffle[list1, list2]~Partition~2`

Comment: the user deserves an explanation why this is closed. It is most certainly not "off topic".

Comment: To closers: Your opinion about a language (Mathematica (TM))you don't know at all isn't welcomed. You should use your close powers in a wiser way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListPlot With Two Data Sets in Mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602991/listplot-with-two-data-sets-in-mathematica)

Comment: @belisarius I like to think I know a thing or two about the language and I'm still voting to close. ;-p  (note the wink)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My rage was about the OT reason, not the closing per se. I think closing a questions requires _at least_ a responsible behavior. But I guess you already know that

Answer (score 20):

If you don't like Pinguin Dirk's suggestion try

```
Transpose[{list1,list2}]
```

Answer (score 8):

yet another..

```
MapThread[ {#1, #2} & , {list1, list2}]
```

or if you want to gracefully handle unequal length lists:

```
MapThread[ {#1, #2} &, Take[#, All, Min @@ Length /@ #] &@{list1, list2} ]
```

Comment: You could even simplify this by using `MapThread[List , {list1, list2}]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another answer that creates a reusable function to pair up two vectors.  The function uses a pure function that maps over the length of the shortest vector to create the pairs.

```
    list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
    list2 = {13, 18, 20, 18, 13};
    pairUp[xValues_ , yValues_] := ({xValues[[#]], yValues[[#]]}) & /@ 
       Range[Min[Length[xValues], Length[yValues]]];

    pairUp[list1, list2]
    (*
      {{1, 13}, {2, 18}, {3, 20}, {4, 18}, {5, 13}}
    *)
```

Hope this helps,

Edmund

PS: New to Mathematica and hoping to improve my understanding by trying to answer a few questions on here from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
Partition[Riffle[x,y],2]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it